# ExtJS: Combo datastores not loading inside a fieldset

Tags: extjs, combobox, datastore

I have a fieldset issue.  The form has a dropdown combo with date ranges the user can select.  The dates are in an ArrayStore.  If I put it outside the fieldset, it works perfectly.  But once inside the fieldset, it will not load the data.  I've tried this with JSON stores as well, with the same result.

Here's the code:

```
{
    name:           'DateFieldSet',
    fieldLabel:     '',
    labelSeparator: ':',
    title:          'Choose a date range',
    collapsible:    false,
    autoHeight:     true,
    allowBlank:     true,
    items:          [
                        {
                            fieldLabel:         'Days in past',
                            hiddenName:         'DateRangeCombo',
                            store:              new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                                                    id:         0,
                                                    fields:     [
                                                                    'rangeValue',
                                                                    'rangeDescription'
                                                    ],
                                                    data:       [
                                                                    [30, '30 days (04/04/2011 - 05/04/2011)'],
                                                                    [60, '60 days (03/05/2011 - 05/04/2011)'],
                                                                    [90, '90 days (02/03/2011 - 05/04/2011)'],
                                                                    [120, '120 days (01/04/2011 - 05/04/2011)'],
                                                                    [180, '180 days (11/05/2010 - 05/04/2011)'],
                                                                    [270, '270 days (08/07/2010 - 05/04/2011)'],
                                                                    [365, '1 year (05/04/2010 - 05/04/2011)']
                                                    ]
                            }),
                            displayField:       'rangeDescription',
                            valueField:         'rangeValue',
                            editable:           true,
                            triggerAction:      'all',
                            width:              150,
                            listeners:          {select:function() {var numberOfDays = ReportForm.form.findField('DateRangeCombo').getValue();var newDate = DateAdd('05/04/2011', 'D', (numberOfDays * -1)); ReportForm.form.findField('StartDate').setValue(newDate);}},
                            xtype:              'combo'
                        },
                        {
                            fieldLabel:         'Or specify your own:',
                            labelStyle:         'width: 100%; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; color: #15428b; font-size: 11px;',
                            labelSeparator:     '',
                            xtype:              'label'
                        },
                        {
                            fieldLabel:         'Start Date',
                            name:               'StartDate',
                            allowBlank:         true,
                            vtype:              '',
                            checked:            false,
                            value:              '04/04/2011',
                            xtype:              'datefield'
                        }, 
                        {
                            fieldLabel:         'End Date',
                            name:               'EndDate',
                            allowBlank:         true,
                            vtype:              '',
                            checked:            false,
                            value:              '05/04/2011',
                            xtype:              'datefield'
                        }
                    ],
    xtype:          'fieldset'
}
```

It looks perfectly normal to me.

EDIT ~ Here's the error:

> this.proxy is undefined

Not that it helps much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you miss `mode` config..

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
        fields: ['rangeValue', 'rangeDescription'],
        data: [
            [30, '30 days (04/04/2011 - 05/04/2011)'],
            [60, '60 days (03/05/2011 - 05/04/2011)'],
            [90, '90 days (02/03/2011 - 05/04/2011)'],
            [120, '120 days (01/04/2011 - 05/04/2011)'],
            [180, '180 days (11/05/2010 - 05/04/2011)'],
            [270, '270 days (08/07/2010 - 05/04/2011)'],
            [365, '1 year (05/04/2010 - 05/04/2011)']
        ]

    }),
    fieldLabel: 'Days in past',
    displayField: 'rangeDescription',
    valueField: 'rangeValue',

    typeAhead: true,
    mode: 'local',    // add this

    triggerAction: 'all',
    emptyText: 'Select date...',
    listeners: {
        select: function () {
            var numberOfDays = ReportForm.form.findField('DateRangeCombo').getValue();
            var newDate = DateAdd('05/04/2011', 'D', (numberOfDays * -1));
            ReportForm.form.findField('StartDate').setValue(newDate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did indeed, thank you.  The reason it worked outside the fieldset and not inside is because the code is 100% dynamic and was being built by two separate code blocks.  I neglected to put the mode parameter in the fieldset method.

Comment: fix it.. the problem is just `mode` config